# Auto width for a counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```js
var counter = 0;

$("#links").click(function(){
  counter = counter - 1;
  $("#mitte a").text(counter);
});

$("#rechts").click(function(){
  counter = counter + 1;
  $("#mitte a").text(counter);
});
```

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:gray;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:arial;
  color:white;
  font-size:200%;
  line-height:100px;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
}
#links {
  background-color:#EF4836;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#links:hover {
  background-color:#AF4836;
}
#mitte {
  background-color:#D2D7D3;
}
#rechts {
  background-color:#1BBC9B;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#rechts:hover {
  background-color:#6BBC9B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="links"><a>-</a></div>
<div class="box" id="mitte"><a>0</a></div>
<div class="box" id="rechts"><a>+</a></div>
```

I created a Counter.

With + and - and in the middle you will see the number but if the number is 10000 you can not see it in the box.

Can someone add a Auto width code for the middle box ?

Comment: Please don't subvert the link restriction and place all relevant code in the question. If CodePen goes down this will be unanswerable.

Comment: Thank you for the Information :)

Comment: What's this got to do with Java?

Comment: @khelwood I think he confused Java and Javascript. For this reason, I suggested an edit where I removed the Java tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
.box {
  width:100px;
}
```

to

```
.box {
  min-width:100px;
}
```

this way it will start at 100px and after 99999 it will increase the width

Comment: @KeremGmsk, perhaps you want to accept this answer:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work